# Rails FactoryGirl trait association with model after_create callback not setting vanity_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

In my model, I have an after_create callback that triggers the method:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :update_vanity_url

  private

  def update_vanity_url
    self.vanity_url = '/jobs/' + company.slug + '/' + slug + '/' + id.to_s + '/'
  end
end
```

This sets up a custom url for my jobs, however, when I try to use this in my coupon factory it is not being saved. The coupon is created without a job assigned. Only when the coupon is used is it paired with one job. I referred to that as executed:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :coupon do
    code { rand(25**25) }
    percent_discount { rand(100**1) }
    start_at { Time.now }
    end_at { 30.day.from_now }

    trait :executed do |c|
      association :job, factory: [:job, :purchased] 
      c.executed_at { Time.now }
    end
  end
end
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to call `FactoryGirl.create(:coupon, :executed)` which works but the after_create is never called... Thoughts?

More details of this setup are covered here [Rails FactoryGirl Factory with optional model association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808602/rails-factorygirl-factory-with-optional-model-association/35812749?noredirect=1#comment59509551_35812749)

Per issue comments below, I have added my routes section and updates:

**Routes**

```
  resources :jobs, only: [:new] do
    collection do
      post 'new', to: 'jobs#create'
    end
    get '/review', to: 'reviews#new'
    patch '/review', to: 'reviews#update'
    get '/payment', to: 'payments#new'
    patch '/payment', to: 'payments#update'
  end
  match '/jobs/:company_slug/:job_slug/:id', via: :get, to: 'jobs#show'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched this for hours, and this is what I found to work. It turns out it was not FactoryGirl, rather the model itself... I think...

```
  def update_vanity_url
    self.vanity_url = '/jobs/' + company.slug + '/' + slug + '/' + id.to_s + '/'
    save
  end
```

Comment: I would reconsider this approach. Your model should not be responsible for routing. Rather this should be handled in your routes.rb file. What you want to have in your model is a '.find_by_id_or_slug' method.

Comment: I tried that approach, but the vanity urls seem to work better per the client SEO spec.  Take a look at my routes I posted, it works like normal rails for everything else, outside the match portion @max

Answer (score 0):

### Your actual question

The problem you're asking about is more a symptom or side effect of how you're doing your lookup.

**tl;dr**: The `vanity_url` attribute is not being saved because `update_vanity_url` is set on an `after_create` callback when the record has already been written to the database. It *is* setting it in memory which is why your tests might've been tripped up by this.

That's why putting `save` in the callback fixed your issue. It's simply saving a `Job` a second time after it's created. This is necessary because you wouldn't have the `id` before it was written to the database.

### Maybe a better solution?

Are you doing anything with the `vanity_url` attribute besides routing to it? I ask because unless you're denormalizing this for speed you may not need to store this on the model at all.

The only thing I came up with is that you might be using those params to construct the `vanity_url` and doing something like `@job = Job.where(vanity_url: vanity_url).first` or something.