# Testing after_save callback evaluating saved_change_to_attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have recently upgraded my application to rails 5.1 causing me to start using `saved_change_to_attribute?` in my `after_save` callbacks. This has caused a test to break.

The code that I am trying to test is the following which gets called through another function in an `after_save`:

**MODEL.RB:**

```
def items_update_needed?
  return (online_only? || saved_change_to_online_only?) &&
         (saved_change_to_published? && !complete? ||
          saved_change_to_online_only? ||
          saved_change_to_listing? ||
          saved_change_to_third_party_bidding_url? ||
          saved_change_to_starts_at? ||
          saved_change_to_scheduled_end_time? ||
          saved_change_to_closing_speed_lots? ||
          saved_change_to_closing_speed_minutes?)
end
```

**TEST.RB:**

```
test "items_update_needed? NOT for a live auction UNLESS it was previous timed" do
  #  Timed auction NEEDS items update if starts_at changes
  @online_only.starts_at = 5.minutes.from_now
  assert @online_only.items_update_needed?
  @online_only.reload
end
```

The assert line fails with an error of: `Expected false to be truthy.`

If I drop a debugger in `items_update_needed?`, `saved_changes_to_starts_at?` returns `false`.

If I put a save before the assert it still returns `false` which makes sense because the function would have been called already through the `after_save` callback.

So I am trying to determine how can you actually test this method and get a return of `true`?

Comment: You forgot to call `save` before stating assertion. As said, the behavior `saved_change_to_attribute?` only actual changed in `after_save` callbacks

Comment: @yeuem1vannam I added the `@online_only.save` and it still isn't returning the expected value.

Comment: Once you call save it will call the callback and then when I do the assert it will call the callback after it has already been called once because the changes have been processed already.

Comment: You can find something useful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677718/how-to-test-models-callback-method-independently?answertab=active#tab-top). Since you are testing the callback behavior, being called twice is not the trouble.